# Extract frames from a video using OpenImaj in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, video-processing, openimaj

```
for (MBFImage mbfImage : video) {
DisplayUtilities.displayName(mbfImage.process(new CannyEdgeDetector()), "videoFrames");
```

I need to **extract frames from a video** and I'm using Java platform.

I'm expecting to use the **OpenIMAJ** Library to do that. I want to know are their any other better solutions for this (*better processing time*)? And also the average processing time and speed of OpenImaj to extract frames from a video.

**Edited:**

I need to extract local video files. I'm not going to implement anything else with OpenIMAJ. I just need OpenIMAJ to extract frames and loop through them. I need to know the time that OpenIMAJ takes to extract frames from a video. Is it something slow, comparing with other libraries(openCV, FFMPEG).

Comment: You need to give us more information... The cost of extracting a frame is usually negligible compared to any processing (what do you want to do with the frame once it's extracted in memory?). What kind of video are you dealing with (a local file; a stream; a camera)? For a video read from a file (using `XuggleVideo`), the rate at which you can get frames is basically the maximum rate at which ffmpeg can give them to you plus a few 10s of milliseconds per frame for packing the data into the right format (the time is dependent on frame size; smaller frames are faster).

Comment: @Jon I need to extract local video files. I'm not going to implement anything else with OpenIMAJ. I just need OpenIMAJ to extract frames and loop through them. I need to know the time that OpenIMAJ takes to extract frames from a video. Is it something slow, comparing with other libraries(openCV, FFMPEG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, OpenIMAJ (and I believe OpenCV, depending on which capture driver is being used) use ffmpeg/libav to do the decoding. I don't believe there should be much difference in performance between any of them.